# mongoose vs mongorito, which one is better?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongorito

I've just arrived in Node.js and MongoDB. I found there are two popular ODM tools for MongoDB. ([Mongoose](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/) and [Mongorito](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/mongorito)). Can I get the pros and cons of those Tools?
Are there better alternatives to these two?

Comment: Why do you use mongo and not other "safer" databases?

Comment: what database do you propose?

Comment: @BehrouzSeyedi That depends.

Comment: @str depends on what?

Comment: @BehrouzSeyedi On your requirements.

Comment: @str I want to start a small project (save bitcoins price for multiple source, every 10 seconds). And I want to learn MngoDB as NoSQL DBMS.
Indeed I want to learn an NoSQL DBMS to manipulate bigdata.

Comment: @BehrouzSeyedi What you describe is far from big data. Most DBMS will easily be able to handle that amount of data. And if you want to learn MongoDB anyway (for that use case), there is no need to use an ODM/ORM at all.

Comment: @str thank you so much :)